# Anylogic-Improving output

Tags: java, queue, output, anylogic, inventory

I have created a simple model with 2 sources.

Agents from `Source` passes through delay and via conveyor to Assembler.

Agents from `Source1` passes through conveyor and go to Assembler. 4 agents of `Source 1` and 1 agent of `Source` is required in Assembler to move forward.

But i see the issue of large queue and low output.

[image]

Can anyone please help me to understand how can I focus on increasing output while reducing the queue size?

Processing Time for Both delay and Assembler has been set to `=Triangular (.5,1,1.5)` and 1 Resource has been used at Assembler. I have tried to increase resources but still queue size remains same.

Comment: Unless you have some logical bugs in your model, your outcomes should just be logical consequences of your setup: source arrival rates, delay capacity/time, conveyer speeds (and agent lengths which determine how many fit onto the conveyer at once) and assembler delay time / resource use / input ratios. Make sure you've used the right time units in all places too. The numbers suggest you have a capacity 1 Delay block with a long delay time (which is why you have a large bottleneck in your first queue which would be unaffected by increasing your assembler resources).

Answer (score 0):

Your assembler is sourced from 2 different streams of the process, lets call units from `source` stream 1 and units from `source1` stream 2. Both streams have the same input, as is evident from the fact that both `source` and `source1` have about the same number of arrivals, 836 and 842 respectively. (Any difference would be purely due to the random arrival times)

The big difference is that stream 1 has a delay in it and the other does not, so it would be natural to expect that stream 1 might have a much higher queue before the assembler, compared to stream 2, since its units are not being delayed before arriving.

To improve the output increasing the resource pool will increase the number of assemblies the assembler block can be busy with at any given time.
But if the output of the assembler is constrained by the next block, in your case a conveyor, it will prevent the assembler from doing more assemblies even if the resources are available.

You can either then add a queue to the end of the assembler or you can increase the `Output buffer capacity` of the assembler block, which is essentially the same.